# how to set the oauth_verifier in the header twitteroauth php

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm getting the following error:

`Error processing your OAuth request: Invalid oauth_verifier parameter`

I keep reading that the issue is that in the library `TwitterOAuth by Abraham` we need to set the oauth_verifier in the header and not the body.

I don't know how to do this.

Here is my code:

// twitterlogin.php

```
session_start();
$twitterKey = 'xxx';
$twitterSecret = 'xxx';
$callback = "https://xxx/socialmedia/twittercallback.php";

require_once("/xxx/twitteroauth/vendor/autoload.php");
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($twitterKey,$twitterSecret);
$result = $twitter->oauth('oauth/request_token', ['oauth_callback' => $callback]);
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $result['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $result['oauth_token_secret'];
$url = $twitter->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $result['oauth_token']));
header("Location: $url");
```

// twittercallback.php

```
session_start();
require_once("/xxx/api");
$twitterKey = 'xxx';
$twitterSecret = 'xxx';
require_once("/xxx/twitteroauth/vendor/autoload.php");
$twitter = new \Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth($twitterKey,$twitterSecret,$_SESSION['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

try {
 $access_token = $twitter->oauth("oauth/access_token", ["oauth_verifier" => $_GET['oauth_verifier']]);
 $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
} catch(\Exception $e){
 print "<pre>".print_r($e,true)."</pre>";
}
var_dump($access_token);
```

How do I set the oauth_verifier in the header?

Thanks!